# how can we pass parameters to custom interceptors preHandler method to add checks in java

Tags: java, parameter-passing, interceptor

is there any way to pass parameter to the interceptor from the client/test class

```
@Component
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
      
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: No, there is no direct way. You could send something with the request, e.g. a HTTP request header. What do you want to check/pass?

Comment: need to disable all endpoints by default, based on the confirmation from requested class we need to hit endpoints.